# RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be non-empty stringss

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
exports.run = async(client, message, args) => {

if(!message.member.permissions.has("0x0000000000000008")) return message.channel.send(`> **Bu komutu kullanabilmek için "\`YÖNETİCİt\`" yetkisine sahip olmalısın.**`)

let mesaj = args[0]
if (!mesaj) return message.channel.send('> **Birşey Yazmalısınız**')

await message.delete()

const mesajat = new Discord.EmbedBuilder()
.setColor(Discord.Colors.Blue)
.setDescription(args.slice(0).join(' '))

message.guild.members.cache.map(async user => {
await user.send({ embeds: [mesajat] }).catch(e => {})
})

await message.channel.send(`> **✅ Mesaj basariyla gonderildi.**`)

}

exports.conf = {
aliases: ['duyurlaherkese']
}

exports.help = {
name: 'duyurherkes'
}
```

I got this error.

> RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be
> non-empty strings.

Screenshot of the error: [Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c86tM.png)

And I get this error too:

> DeprecationWarning: MessageEmbed#addField is deprecated and will be
> removed in the next major update. Use MessageEmbed#addFields instead.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the error:

> RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values must be
> non-empty strings.

Points us to the `EmbedBuilder`, specifically the `setDescription` call. [The values can't be `''`, `null`, or `undefined`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73188750/addfields-in-embedbuilder-doesnt-support-empty-string). So, on this line:

```
.setDescription(args.slice(0).join(' '))
```

You must ensure that `args` isn't an empty array. Try calling it with a generic string. If it works, then you must figure out why `args` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

This error message is indicating that the .setDescription(args.slice(0).join(' ')) line is trying to set the description of the embed to an empty string. This is because the args[0] that you are trying to use as the message is not being passed in properly.

The second error message is indicating that the MessageEmbed#addField method is deprecated and will be removed in future versions of discord.js, and you should use MessageEmbed#addFields instead.

You can fix this by making sure that the message passed in as an argument is being passed in properly, and also update the addField method to addFields.